# Jump to an org agenda clock from an org agenda clock report

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, org-clock

Here's an example Org clock table in Emacs:

```
#+BEGIN: clocktable :maxlevel 1 :scope file :tcolumns 1 :formula %
#+CAPTION: Clock summary at [2014-03-30 Sun 22:47]
| Headline     |   Time |     % |
|--------------+--------+-------|
| *Total time* | *4:31* | 100.0 |
|--------------+--------+-------|
| Item A       |   1:07 |  24.7 |
| Item B       |   1:06 |  24.4 |
| Item C       |   2:18 |  50.9 |
#+TBLFM: $3='(org-clock-time% @2$2 $2..$2);%.1f
#+END:
```

Is it possible to move my cursor over `Item B` and run a command that would take me to `Item B`'s clock? If so, is it possible to do the reverse and jump from the clock to the clock's row in the Org clock table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I figured this out - sorry for the brevity. I need to add a `link:` attribute in my org clock BEGIN statement. For the above example, I need to make it look like this:

```
#+BEGIN: clocktable :maxlevel 1 :scope file :tcolumns 1 :formula :link %
```

Then the items will be rendered as link, and I can either click or execute the function `M-x org-agenda-open-link`, which will open a new buffer with the cursor over the org clock item.